# .htaccess file not working with certain servers

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Hello and thank you for taking the time to help me solve my problem. I like to build all of my web projects using a simple MVC Framework I have created along my travels. I seem to be having a problem getting the `.htaccess` file to work correctly on specific servers.

For example...

If you go to:

http://thomsonbrothersindustries.com/northside/ and attempt to access a page (right now only "About Us" is functional - http://thomsonbrothersindustries.com/northside/about) but as you can see the "about" page just directs you to a **404 Error**.

Now, if you go to: (the same site, but on a different server)

http://ericzdisposal.com/northside/

http://ericzdisposal.com/northside/about

everything works fine...

Here is the .HTACCESS file:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?rt=$1 [L,QSA]
```

My privileges are limited on the server that is currently not working and I'm still working on getting better access to domain tools, but in the meantime I'm just trying to get a better idea of the problem and hoping there might be an easy fix in my future.

Comment: make sure mod_rewrite is enabled in your apache config

Comment: What OS/distribution are the servers on?

Comment: Looks like Windows, but I'm not 100% positive. My client setup most of the hosting circa 1999 so I'm trying to gather all the information now. DNS is pointing to www.1and1.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like adding the directory into the .htaccess file did the trick!

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ **/northside/**index.php?rt=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I didn't realize this was important because on the other server it did not matter

Thanks all!

Comment: You should check out [RewriteBase](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase) setting.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @bigman suggested, make sure that `AllowOverride` directive setting is not very restrictive for your website directory. For mod_rewrite to work in .htaccess, you need to set `AllowOverride FileInfo`, but for testing purposes, you can set `AllowOverride All`.

Comment: Also make sure nobody changed the `AccessFileName` setting, you could set `AccessFileName .htaccess` to make sure it's the default